# Where can I find a list of correspondences between mongodb Windows and mongodb Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, mongodb

For example (I wonder if all these should be separate questions):

1. What would be the equivalent of mongod.exe in Linux?
2. What's the equivalent of mongodb.conf in Windows?
3. How do we make mongodb to launch when computer start in Windows?

For example, in mongodb windows, I have this file called mongod.exe running it run the mongod "service" or something and then it shows status of what's going on at mongodb.

For example this is what mongod.exe shows:

```
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6232] end connection 127.0.0.1:19782
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19783 #
33
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6233] end connection 127.0.0.1:19783
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19784 #
34
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6234] end connection 127.0.0.1:19784
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19785 #
35
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6235] end connection 127.0.0.1:19785
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19786 #
36
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6236] end connection 127.0.0.1:19786
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19787 #
37
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:19788 #
38
Fri Aug 31 16:08:13 [conn6238] end connection 127.0.0.1:19788
```

What would be the equivalent of mongod.exe in linux?

Also in Linux we have this thing called mongodb.conf where we set up, for example, where the data directory is. In windows, what's the equivalent of mongodb.conf in windows? In windows, if I want to change data directory I simply copy and move the whole mongod directory. I am not even sure whether that's the right way to do it.

Then in Linux, once I install mongodb it's automatically run everytime I restarted the server. In windows I have to run mongod.exe first. Hmm... How can I arrange that mongodb run automatically as a service in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the equivalent of mongod.exe in Linux?

Answer: mongod (Linux does not use file extensions to denote executables)

> What's the equivalent of mongodb.conf in Windows?

They are identical - this is just a text file on both systems, you can use the same one on both (after adjusting for file path differences etc.)

> How do we make mongodb to launch when computer start in Windows?

You install it as a service, as outlined here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service